bitnami Kafka configuration with kraft with username/password docker-compose
I want to create kraft kafka with docker-compose.yaml I have used below code and it works fine but Now I want to enable authentication via username/password but nothing works. I have tried with many methods but nothing work.
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka-benthos
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
    networks:
      - benthos
    environment:
        # KRaft settings
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka:9093
      # Listeners
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-benthos:9092,CONTROLLER://kafka-benthos:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://192.168.50.111:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT

Can you please explain changes to enable SASL authentication using username/password?
I have tried below configuration but it not working.
environment:
      # KRaft settings
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_CONTROLLER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS=PLAIN
      # Listeners
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka-benthos:9092,CONTROLLER://kafka-benthos:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://192.168.50.111:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
      - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_USER=user
      - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_PASSWORD=bitnami
      - KAFKA_CLIENT_USERS=user
      - KAFKA_CLIENT_PASSWORDS=bitnami


The controller shouldn't need it, but the INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT mapping isn't using SASL for internal docker network clients
